# How to fire a select node event of a jsTree after re-populting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jstree

I have a requirement of populating my jsTree and firing few ajax calls on selection of any node of jsTree which I am able to it. But the problem is I have to re-populate the same tree and firing that ajax call again. After re-populating, I am not able to firing that SELECT or CLICK NODE event on selection of any tree node. Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="//static.jstree.com/3.2.1/assets/dist/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="//static.jstree.com/3.2.1/assets/dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#tree").on("select_node.jstree", function(event, node) {
    $("#para").text("");
    var selected = node.instance.get_selected();
    if(selected.length === 1) {
      $("#para").text(selected[0]); // Here goes my ajax call.
    } else if(selected.length > 1) {
      alert("hi");
    }
  });

});

function getData(){
    $('#tree').jstree("destroy").empty();


    $('#tree').jstree({
       'core' : {
         'data' : [
           { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node1" },
           { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
           { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
           { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
         ]
       }
     });
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a id="go" href="#" onclick="getData()">Get Tree</a><br><br><br><br>


<div id="tree"></div>

<p id="para"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

You can paste this code directly in w3school site and test. Not able make a jsFiddle of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a seperate function to add event listener.. then call that function from Doc ready, as well at the end of getData(). like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function addEventListener(){
        $("#tree").on("select_node.jstree", function(event, node) {
            $("#para").text("");
            var selected = node.instance.get_selected();
            if(selected.length === 1) {
              $("#para").text(selected[0]); // Here goes my ajax call.
            } else if(selected.length > 1) {
              alert("hi");
            }
          });
      }

      addEventListener();

      function getData(){
        $('#tree').jstree("destroy").empty();
        $('#tree').jstree({
           'core' : {
             'data' : [
               { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node1" },
               { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
               { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
               { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
             ]
           }
         });
         addEventListener();
      }
 })
```

Comment: This seems working in my demo app. Let me test it in my real application. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Husnain. Its working. I edited your code, removed what was not required.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a node programmatically by following line of code.

```js
$('#treeSelector').jstree().select_node('node_id');
```

It will trigger select_node & change event too.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!